# Returning subset of dictionary with a complex type as a key with Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I have a collection as follows

```
Private _bankRates As Dictionary(Of RateSourceBank.Key, RateSourceBank)
```

Where RateSourceBank.Key is simply

```
Public Class Key
    Public RateType As String
    Public EffectiveDate As DateTime
End Class
```

How can I retrieve a **subset of _bankRates that have more than one EffectiveDate per RateType?**

Unfortunately all similar examples I find are in C# and I fond the LINQ translation somewhat less than straightforward, especially when it comes to the group by syntax, e.g. with query below

```
Dim ratesWithDuplicates = From rates In _bankRates
                          Group rates By rates.Key.RateType
                          Into grp()
                          Where grp.Count > 1
```

I receive error:

> Definition of method 'grp' is not accessible in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the snippet you're looking for

```
Dim ratesWithDuplicates =
    From rates In _bankRates
    Group rates By rates.Key.RateType Into Group
    Where Group.Count() > 1
```

The expression / keyword `Group` represents the collection.  You can give it a different name by using the `name = Group` syntax

```
Dim ratesWithDuplicates =
    From rates In _bankRates
    Group rates By rates.Key.RateType Into someName = Group
    Where someName.Count() > 1
```